# String comparison by splitting in jruby

Tags: ruby, jruby

I am trying to get the numeric value out of a string which looks like "ABCDEFG [1]". Here I am trying to get 1. I tried to use split method on the following string but dint get success. Any solution for this is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please post the code that you tried to give us somewhere to start from.

Comment: How about `"ABCDEFG [1]".match('\d')`?

Comment: Have you tried using regex instead?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
def get_numeric_value(str)
  # Match a number surrounded by square brackets
  matchdata = str.match(/\[\d+\]/)
  if matchdata
    # Get the first matched substring, and remove the first and last characters
    # (which will be the square brackets)
    number = matchdata[0][1..-2]
    number.to_i
  else
    nil
  end
end

get_numeric_value "ABCDEFG [1]" #=> 1
```

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. I wanted to compare the number present in square brackets with 0 and then perform various operations if it is greater than or less than 0. I did not use regex instead I used "count" method and it works fine for me.